# PHP add iTXt comment to a PNG image

Tags: php, png

I have looked around for this everywhere. I know it can be done using some libraries in .net, but I really want my script to generate a "marked" image. The reason is that we are a forum host, and have teamed up with a theme making company. The theme making company wants us to be able to track down any illegally distributed themes. I saw the iTXt comment in the GCHQ CanYouCrackIt exercise and think it'll be the best, no intrusive method of protecting our property.

Comment: ImageMagick seems to be able to do this - see http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=18891 it doesn't look like there is a ready-made solution for PHP around.

Answer (score 8):

A suggestion: If you have a fixed [iTXt](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11iTXt) chunk that you want to add to an image, a quick and dirty procedure could be to simply insert it just before the IEND chunk (12 bytes) of the original image. This should work, because the iTXt can be placed before of after the image data. Of course, this does not check if the chunk as already there.

Here's an example code, using the `tEXt` chunk (slightly simpler), it needs some polishing but it basically works:

```
<?php   

    addTextToPngFile("x.png","x2.png","Watermark","Hi this is a TEXT test");

    function addTextToPngFile($pngSrc,$pngTarget,$key,$text) {
        $chunk = phpTextChunk($key,$text);
        $png = file_get_contents($pngSrc);
        $png2 = addPngChunk($chunk,$png);
        file_put_contents($pngTarget,$png2);
    }

    // creates a tEXt chunk with given key and text (iso8859-1)
    // ToDo: check that key length is less than 79 and that neither includes null bytes
    function phpTextChunk($key,$text) {
        $chunktype = "tEXt";
        $chunkdata = $key . "\0" . $text;
        $crc = pack("N", crc32($chunktype . $chunkdata));
        $len = pack("N",strlen($chunkdata));
        return $len .  $chunktype  . $chunkdata . $crc;
    }

    // inserts chunk before IEND chunk (last 12 bytes)
    function addPngChunk($chunk,$png) {
        $len = strlen($png);
        return substr($png,0,$len-12) . $chunk . substr($png,$len-12,12);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there any way of adding dynamic text instead of taking the iTXt from one image to another (which is what I think this snippet is doing)?

Comment: @Tommykent1210 : the text is dynamic here, see the first line of my code. Only that this is tEXt instead of iTXt , but if you really need iTXt it's easy to change.

Comment: there are no two input images (source=original target=final)